# I got problems with FlyControls.js

Tags: three.js

Below is my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
// Set scene size
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth, HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
// WebGL's object
var container = null, renderer = null, scene = null, camera = null;
var controls = null, stats = null;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
// Target geometry
var mesh = null;

// Initialize WebGL
function initWebGL() {
    setupRenderer();
    setupScene();
    setupCamera();
    setupLight();
}

// Initialize renderer
function setupRenderer() {
    // Create the canva element
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        clearColor: 0x999999,
        clearAlpha: 1.0
    });
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    // Add the canvas into its container
    container = $('#canvas-container-1');
    container.append(renderer.domElement);
}

// Initialize scene
function setupScene() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    render();
}

// Initialize camera
function setupCamera() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            45,
            WIDTH / HEIGHT,
            0.1,
            1000
            );
    camera.position.set(-5, 13, 10);

    // Camera controls
    controls = new THREE.FlyControls(camera);
    controls.domElement = container;
    controls.movementSpeed = 10;
    controls.rollSpeed = Math.PI / 12;

    controls.dragToLook = true;

    scene.add(camera);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
}

// Add lights to the scene
function setupLight() {
    var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x777777);
    light.position.set(10, 30, 20);
    scene.add(light);

    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
    light.position.set(250, 250, 250);
    scene.add(light);
}

// Call animation loop
function update(loop) {
    // Update camera control
    controls.update(clock.getDelta());
    // Update renderer
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

// Main mesh
function addMesh() {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load("models/demo/bmw.js", function(geometry) {
        // Init mesh's materials
        var materials = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
        // Init mesh
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
                geometry,
                materials
                //geometry.materials
                );
        // Add mesh to the scene
        scene.add(mesh);
        // Animation
        (function loop() {
            //mesh.rotation.y += 0.005;
            update(loop);
        })();
    });
}

// Floor plane
function addFloor() {
    var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/textures/grey-concrete-texture-01.jpg');
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    floorTexture.repeat.set(100, 100);
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: floorTexture,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.position.y = 0;
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add(floor);
}

// Rendering
function render() {
    // Mesh
    addMesh();
    // Floor
    addFloor();
}
</script>
```

My model was loaded ok ... but some problems happened ...

- When the `controls.dragToLook` property is `false` ... Refresh the webpage and I can see my loaded models, but if I move my mouse, all of my loaded models is gone right then ...
- When the `controls.dragToLook` property is `true` ... the preceding problem was end but after several click on the scene, everything is disappeared again ... I cannot handle this problem ...

Please help me!

Comment: FlyControls is not part of the library, it is part of the examples -- there are no guarantees. Consider using one of the other controls, instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. So, what should I use in stead of "FlyControls.js"?

Comment: It depends on your application. You could try `FirstPersonControls` or `OrbitControls`.

Answer (score 1):

Only replying to this because I ran across this thread trying to fix same issue.  Had some luck in replacing:

```
controls = new THREE.FlyControls(camera);
controls.domElement = container;
```

with

```
controls = new THREE.FlyControls(camera, container);
```

Note, this did not make my mouse controls work, it merely disabled them and prevented them from breaking my project again.